# Stopping/pausing a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to programming and I have a question about threads. I am writing a programm which has a start, a stop and a restart button. When the start button is pressed it counts up every second and displays this on a label. When you press stop the programm should stop counting. Afterwards you can press start and it counts up from where it has stopped. When you press restart it should restart counting from 0.
My problem is that it counts up but it never stops when I am pressing the stop button.

```
    import javafx.application.Platform;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;

    public class TimerThread extends Thread {
    private int seconds = 0;
    private boolean enabled = false;

  
    private Label labelToUpdate;

    public TimerThread(int seconds, Label labelFromGUI) {
        this.seconds = seconds;
        this.labelToUpdate = labelFromGUI;
    }

    public void setLabelToUpdate(Label labelToUpdate) {
        this.labelToUpdate = labelToUpdate;
    }

    public void enable() {
        enabled = true;
    }

    public void disable() {
        enabled = false;
    }

    public int getSeconds() {
        return seconds;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (enabled) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            ++seconds;
          
            
            Platform.runLater(
                    new Thread() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            
    labelToUpdate.setText(String.valueOf(seconds));
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
    }
    }

    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class Controller {

    public Button startButton;
    public Button stopButton;
    public Label secondsLabel;

    public void startButtonClicked(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        TimerThread t = new TimerThread(0, secondsLabel);
        // t.setLabelToUpdate(secondsLabel); // Alternative zum Konstrutor

        t.enable();
        t.start();
    }

    public void stopButtonClicked(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    }

public void resetButtonClicked(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    }
}
```

Comment: You should consider coding something in the stopButtonClicked method :)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you need to do is to make 'enabled' volatile. Currently there is a data race on the write and the read of the field and the JIT compiler could optimize the code like this:

```
if(!enabled)
    return;

while(true){
    ... do stuff
}
```

And now it is obvious the loop will never stop.